# Flask - show progress bar while function progress before sending data to html

Tags: python, flask

I try to build a web app which makes video process and send processed video back with the code below.The process funtions do this job byte by byte so we have that data which are file size and byte remaining

I am using that code block to let the users download a file -serverside

```
@app.route('/file',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def file():
video process functions


    def generate():
            try:
               f=open(path,"rb")
               yield from f
             finally:
               f.close()
               os.remove(path)            



      r = app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='audio/mp3',
content_type="audio")
      r.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
      r.set_cookie('ho',value='values')
      return r
```

There is a simple form

```
<form id="you-form" action="{{url_for('file')}}" method="GET">
```

the codes work fine but the app can calculate how much remaining while makin video process so ı want to show this clint with progress bar.

If you need more information please ask

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: you have to use javascript with ajax or websockets, so that your client webpage running in the browser sends a separate request to get the current percentage.

Comment: Thanks for help ,It is so obvious that i have to use javascript.Ajax is not suitable for my purpose but maybe websockets but i couldnt find how to intagrate to request .Thanks again

Comment: You can do it with ajax too, I've done it before. Create a function and make Javascript call it periodically using `setInterval`, inside the function do AJAX request to the server. Make your flask app answer this request with the current percentage to display. The javascript function will get this and update the client screen.

Comment: Yes that s right @nosklo but the is that as you see the app send the data back to let user download it  by using generate yield as i know ajax is not able to get this yield  it only fetchs static file to let the user get file.any extra information will be appriciated thanks for your comment

Comment: You shouldn't use ajax to transfer the file itself, continue transfering it normally as you are already doing! Use ajax only to transfer the number that indicates the percentage of the file already downloaded.... This would happen in a separate function

Comment: Ajax needs a different url to get the percentage but all video conversion and process is made under this url @app.route('/file',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) .So ı have to make other route fro comminicate with ajax but how i passed the from route(/file) to route(/routeforajax) Thank you for your advices @nosklo

Comment: in your `yield` function, add code to store the current percentage in the instance of your class, as a dict attribute:  `self.file_transfer_perc[filename] = percentage` -- you can then access this in your ajax function: `return json.dumps(self.file_transfer_perc[filename])`

Comment: You can use AJAX on client side to render a progress bar, and to download file, use Javascript redirect. Another way may be streaming from Flask. Not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: @nosklo where does it store data(percentage) to ? a temporary text file or variable ? could you be more expicit?

Comment: @digging to a variable: `self.file_transfer_perc` - assuming you're using a class. But it could be a global variable too

Comment: @nosklo thanks for patient ! lastly,thats variable wont be global ! how to reach this variable in other function or do i have to make a global variable so two funtions can reach it  (as you know every request equals a funciton)

Comment: @digging The usual way to share variables between functions is to use a class and store the variables as instance attributes. If you're not using classes, then yes, you need global variables

Comment: thanks everybody especially @nosklo i ll try your suggestions and advice